# CloudKit Dashboard says I have no iCloud containers, but I have already created 2. What might be the issue?

Tags: cloudkit

I have already created 2 containers for 2 App IDs with CloudKit enabled. However, when I access the CloudKit Dashboard, it says that I do not have any CloudKit-enabled apps? What is the issue?

Comment: Can you give us more information? Did you already run your app? Did you try writing and reading data do the container? If you configure an app for iCloud, then the container should be created the moment you try to save something to it. Just try writing a record from your app.

Comment: I've encountered this before, but it was my mistake. I logged in to iCloud dashboard with an Apple ID that has not been used with the app before and is not the developer account for that app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you click on `CloudKit` select option? I think the CloudKit Dashboard is only available if that option was ticked.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

if you already have an app with app id and bundle id then do the following steps:

**Add iCloud container**

1. go to your member center (https://developer.apple.com/membercenter)
2. click on "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles"
3. click “iCloud Containers” from the left menu
4. choose add or “+” sign
5. add text in the “Description” textfield
6. name your container (usually iCloud.com.myDomain.myApp style)
7. click “Continue”
8. review the summary screen and click “Register”
9. click "Done"

**Enable iCloud feature to your app**

1. go to your member center (https://developer.apple.com/membercenter)
2. click on "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles"
3. click "App IDs" from the left menu
4. click on the app you want to add iCloud features (center of the screen)
5. click on the "Edit" button from the lower center screen
6. scroll down and tick the iCloud option
7. it will ask if to enable iCloud click "OK"
8. choose include cloudKit support
9. from the popup alert "Switch to iCloud (Include CloudKit support)" click "OK"
10. click on the "Edit" button and select the iCloud container you created in the previous steps and choose continue
11. review the summary screen and click Assign
12. you should see a "You have successfully modified your iCloud Containers." message
13. click "Done"

now you can click on button “CloudKit Dashboard” from Xcode or go to https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard
it should work